# How to make a plus minus toggle with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to make a plus / minus toggle with angular.  As a basic function, it would let the user enter in two numbers on either side of the toggle as inputs and then, depending upon which toggle was selected, either adds the numbers or subtracts them.
I'm trying to put this in a directive so you could call it multiple times (so if you wanted to add, subtract or do combination of the two for multiple numbers, you could).  I've gotten it to switch what is displayed, but I can't figure out how to get it to do the proper math.

Here is what I have so far:

On plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PW990KXShDEYN9welhPe?p=preview

The html:

```
<input type="number" size="2" ng-model="values.firstValue" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" required>
<plus-minus-toggle></plus-minus-toggle>
<input type="number" size="2" ng-model="values.secondValue" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers">
<plus-minus-toggle></plus-minus-toggle> 
<input type="number" size="2" ng-model="values.thirdValue" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers">
<button ng-click="doMath()">Calculate</button>
{{result}}
```

The directive:

```
angular.module('diceAngularApp')
.directive('plusMinusToggle', function() {  
  return {
    restrict: 'E',      
    scope:true,
    template: '<button ng-click="custom=!custom"><span ng-show="custom">+</span><span ng-hide="custom">-</span></button>',
    replace: true
  };  
});
```

And the controller:

```
angular.module('diceAngularApp')
  .controller('DiceController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $log) {
    $scope.custom = true;
    $rootScope.onlyNumbers = /^\d+$/;

    $scope.values = {firstValue: 5, secondValue: 2, thirdValue: 3};

    $scope.doMath = function() {
       $scope.result = $scope.values.firstValue + $scope.values.secondValue + $scope.values.thirdValue;
    };
});
```

Comment: off-topic: a layout suggestion: [Plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/WsWhewTSVDldiLQkROBP?p=preview)

Comment: That does look nice. I just put that up as a rough sketch. The version on my website does this inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on plunker that isolates the scope of the directive and provides a two-way binding with the parent controller: http://plnkr.co/edit/V7iIQUdSj4tNcRQCn16n?p=preview

The basic idea is to make the directive "re-usable" by isolating its scope:

```js
app.directive('plusMinusToggle', function() {
  function plusOperation(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
  function minusOperation(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      operation: '='
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="isPlus=!isPlus"><span ng-show="isPlus">+</span><span ng-hide="isPlus">-</span></button>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.isPlus = true;
      $scope.operation = plusOperation;
      $scope.$watch('isPlus', function(isPlus) {
        if (isPlus) {
          $scope.operation = plusOperation;
        } else {
          $scope.operation = minusOperation;
        }
      });
    },
    replace: true
  };  
});
```

So in your controller you would have two variables that can be used for the two-way bind:

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $log) {
  $scope.op1 = angular.noop;
  $scope.op2 = angular.noop;
})
```

And in your view is where you make that two-way bind happen:

```html
<plus-minus-toggle operation="op1"></plus-minus-toggle>
<plus-minus-toggle operation="op2"></plus-minus-toggle>
```

Back in the `MainCtrl` you can make use of those operations which will be changed based on the directive's isolated scope:

```
$scope.doMath = function() {
  $scope.result = $scope.op2($scope.op1($scope.values.firstValue, $scope.values.secondValue), $scope.values.thirdValue);
};
```

You can read more about it in the [Isolating the Scope of a Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) section of the angular guide.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Thank you so much. I must say I did read that, but I'm still really confused about scope in general when it comes to Angular. I'll give it another read and see if more sinks in now that I've seen your wonderful example to work with. Thank you.

Comment: @firexion [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) and [$rootScope.$new](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new) are also excellent resources.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your directive include both the input and the button.  That way you have an operation attached to a number.  Set your $scope.values to be an array of objects that have a value and an operation (the first object doesn't have an operation).

```
 $scope.values = [
      {
        value: 5,
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        op: '+'
      },
      {
        value: 3,
        op: '-'
      }
      ];
```

Now you can do an ng-repeat to display the inputs and buttons.  This makes it easy to add more inputs/buttons.

```
<span ng-repeat="v in values">
  <plus-minus-toggle value="v"></plus-minus-toggle>  
</span>
```

Here's the directive:

```
app.directive('plusMinusToggle', function() {  
  return {
    restrict: 'E',      
    scope:{
      value: '='
    },
    template: '<span><button ng-show="showButton(value.op)" ng-click="buttonClick()"><span ng-bind="value.op"></span></button><input type="number" size="2" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" ng-model="value.value"/></span>',
    replace: true,
    link: function($scope, elem, attr){
      $scope.onlyNumbers  = /^\d+$/;
      $scope.showButton = function(op){
        return op != undefined;
      }
      $scope.buttonClick = function(){
        if($scope.value.op == '+')
          $scope.value.op = '-';
        else
          $scope.value.op = '+';
      }
    }
  };  
});
```

This method would also make it fairly simple to add multiplication or division options (clicking the button could cycle through the options).

Here's a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/oGjZkAQJ55tvmJ1wIjgM?p=preview).

Comment: I really like this version. I can understand what's going on a lot better then I could with the version provided by potatosalad. I feel like the way he provided it might 'technically' be the better way, but I can understand and manipulate this a bit easier.  It makes so much sense to store the operation inside a hash with the value, I can't believe I never considered that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

see if this will work for you:

```
$('div[id^="modtab-"]').click(function(){
```

$(this).find('.modtab-toggle').attr("src", function(i, attr){
               var o = this.src.indexOf('plus') > -1 ? this.src.replace('plus', 'minus') :      this.src.replace('minus', 'plus');
              return o;
          });
          });

```
        <div id="tab-module-row-1">
        </div>

 <div class="module-row module-tab pull-right" id="modtab-sql_dss">
     <img src="images/icons/icon-orangebox-plus.png" class="modtab-toggle">
 </div>

<div id="tab-module-row-2">
</div>
```

Comment: If I'm reading this right, this looks like what it does is replace an image with a plus sign with an image with a minus sign when it's clicked, and vice-versa.  As far as I can tell, there isn't anything that would alter the math function in my controller, which is what I was looking for. Please correct me if I'm wrong as I'm very very new to angularjs and jquery.

Comment: Nope you are right - sorry about that, thought that might work for ya.

Answer (score 0):

I just have some suggestions on the layout:
 **http://plnkr.co/edit/WsWhewTSVDldiLQkROBP?p=preview**.

I have to be honest, this angular stuff looks very unsettling to me, I wouldn't know where to implement new functions.

**But I can give you some general pointers:**

I would make a function

```
function math(op,num1,num2) {
    switch (op) {
        case 'add': return num1+num2;
        case 'sub': return num1-num2;
        case 'mul': return num1*num2;
        case 'dev': return num1/num2;
        //etc
    }
}
```

- And then you'd have to store the subresult from two fields and use that value together with the value of the next field
- Clicking the "calculate" button calls a function, in that function you use a for-loop to go past every input field, and call the above function.

  - get the numbers from the inputfield and the operation from the operation-buttons.

---

For switching the operations on the operation-buttons:

- put all operations in an array; `op=['+','-','×','÷',etc]`
- and then in the function you call from the calculate-button, you check on those strings to determine which operation must be performed between two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily recommend using the latest version angularjs:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
```

The second section of the field into separate and independent indexed scope with:

```
<field ng-repeat="case in cases"></field>
```

and introduce objects corresponding to the current field as event function "toggle(case)"

```
app.directive('field', function() {  
  return {
    restrict: 'E',      
    scope: true,
    template: '<div>\
                <input type="number"\
                       size="2"\
                       ng-model="case.value"\
                       ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" required>\
                  <button ng-if="!$last"\
                          ng-click="toggle(case)">\
                    <span>{{ case.custom }}</span>\
                  </button>\
              </div>',
    replace: true,
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.toggle = function (ths) {
        ths.custom = ths.custom === "+" ? ths.custom = "-" : ths.custom = "+";
      }
    }
  };
```

Finally create data fields for our:

```
$scope.cases = [{value: 5, custom: "+"}, {value: 2, custom: "+"}, {value: 3, custom: "+"}, {value: 100, custom: ""}];
```

and put observer fields, if one of them changes, the function is to execute:

```
$scope.$watch('cases', function () {
  var result = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.cases.length; i++) {
    result += $scope.cases[i].value + $scope.cases[i].custom
  }
  $scope.result = $window.eval(result);
}, true)
```

Third argument say that we follow the object and put "true".

Implementation here http://plnkr.co/edit/Ztt8DXf7RsZG0MTcF8Zi?p=preview